# Repeat checker goes back to menu even after entering N to input

Tags: c++

The goal is to create a five-in-one program for various math stuff. The individual blocks work. After selecting and using a block, the program should then send a prompt asking the user whether to go back to the menu or terminate the program, this also works.

However, the function which checks whether you've inputted "Y", "y", "N", or "n" does not work. Instead, it automatically returns you to the main menu even after inputting "N" or "n", which should terminate the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cctype>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool Primecheck(int x){
    // checks if prime is positive or nah
    if (x <= 1)
        return false;
 
    // Check from 2 to n-1
    for (int i = 2; i < x; i++)
        if (x % i == 0)
            return false;
 
    return true;
}


void Repeatcheck(char repeat){
    //checks whether you inputted anything other than Y, y, N, or n
    while (repeat != 'Y' && repeat != 'y' && repeat != 'N' && repeat != 'n' ){
        system("cls");
        std::cout << "that's not an option, dumbass." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\n Return to main menu? Y/N"  << std::endl;
        cin >> repeat;
    }
}



int main()
{
    //Option selection
    int OptSel; 
    //repeat selection
    char repeat; 
    repeat = 'Y';
    //Optsel 1
    int prime, i, primed2=0, flag=0;   
    //Optsel 2 
    int j,rows; 
    //Optsel 3
    int t1 = 0, t2 = 1, nextTerm = 0;
    //Optsel 4 
    int factorialinput;
    long factorial = 1.0;
    
    
    do{
        system("cls");
        repeat = 'Y';
        startoptsel:
        std::cout << "\n----MATHS PROGRAM----" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\n wats poppin?" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "1.) prime number checker" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "2.) right triangle drawer" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "3.) fibonacci" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "4.) factorial" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "5.) exit" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> OptSel;
        
    //check whether option seleccted is available.
        if (!std::cin || OptSel <= 0 || OptSel > 5) { 
            system("cls");
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
            std::cout << "\nThat's not an option, dumbass." << std::endl;
            std::cout << "\nInput numbers from 1-5." << std::endl;
            goto startoptsel;
        }
        
        if (OptSel == 1) {
            system("cls");
            primechecker:
            std::cout << "\n----Prime number checker----" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Enter number: " << std::endl;
            std::cin >> prime;
            // auto filters everything as not prime below 1 
            primed2=prime/2;  
            for(i = 2; i <= primed2; i++){  
                if(prime % i == 0)  
                  {  
                    cout << "\n " << prime << " is not a prime."<<endl;  
                    flag=1;  
                    break;  
                  }  
              }  
            if (flag==0)  
                cout << "\n " << prime << " is a prime."<<endl; 
            if (!cin) {
                system("cls");
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
                std::cout << "please input a number" << std::endl;
                goto primechecker;
            }
        std::cout << "\n Return to main menu? Y/N"  << std::endl;
        cin>>repeat;
        Repeatcheck(repeat);
        }
    
        if (OptSel == 2) {
            system("cls");
            triangledrawer:
            cout << "\n----RIGHT TRIANGLE DRAWER----" << std::endl;
            cout << "\nInput number of rows: ";
            cin >> rows;
            for(i=1;i<=rows;i++){
                for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
                   cout<< ' ' << j;
                cout<<endl;
            }
            if (!cin) {
                system("cls");
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
                std::cout << "please input a number" << std::endl;
                goto triangledrawer;
            }
            std::cout << "\n Return to main menu? Y/N"  << std::endl;
            cin>>repeat;
            Repeatcheck(repeat);
        }
        
        if (OptSel == 3){
            system("cls");
            fibonacciprinter:
            cout << "\n----Fibonacci printer----";
            cout << "\nEnter the number of terms: ";
            cin >> prime;
        
            cout << "Fibonacci Series: ";
        
            for (int i = 1; i <= prime; ++i) {
                // Prints the first two terms.
                if(i == 1) {
                    cout << t1 << ", ";
                    continue;
                }
                if(i == 2) {
                    cout << t2 << ", ";
                    continue;
                }
                nextTerm = t1 + t2;
                t1 = t2;
                t2 = nextTerm;
                
                cout << nextTerm << ", ";
            }
            if (!cin) {
                system("cls");
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
                std::cout << "please input a number" << std::endl;
                goto fibonacciprinter;
            }
            std::cout << "\n Return to main menu? Y/N"  << std::endl;
            cin>>repeat;
            Repeatcheck(repeat);
        }
        
        if (OptSel == 4){   
            system("cls");
            cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
            cin >> factorialinput;
            cout << "Factorial of ";
            if (factorialinput < 0)
                cout << "Error! Factorial of a negative number doesn't exist.";
            else {
                for(int i = 1; i <= factorialinput; ++i) {
                    cout << i << "  ";
                    factorial *= i;
                }
                cout << "= " << factorial;    
            }
            std::cout << "\n Return to main menu? Y/N"  << std::endl;
            cin>>repeat;
            Repeatcheck(repeat);
            repeat = repeat;

        }
        if (repeat == 'n' || repeat == 'N'){
        
            system("cls");
            std::cout << "\nJob done? JOB DONE! Aight wrap it up lesgo." << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }while (OptSel != 5);
    
    system("cls");
    std::cout << "\nJob done? JOB DONE! Aight wrap it up lesgo." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Rewriting the program to instead run when repeat = Y or y and removing the specific instance of terminating the program when N or n is entered instead results in the program terminating automatically no matter what is inputted when the Repeatcheck function is called.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cctype>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool Primecheck(int x){
    ...
}


void Repeatcheck(char repeat){
    while (repeat != 'Y' && repeat != 'y' && repeat != 'N' && repeat != 'n' ){
            system("cls");
            std::cout << "that's not an option, dumbass." << std::endl;
            std::cout << "\n Return to main menu? Y/N"  << std::endl;
            cin >> repeat;
    }
}



int main()
{
    ...
    
    do{

        ...

    }while (OptSel != 5 && repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y');
    
    system("cls");
    std::cout << "\nJob done? JOB DONE! Aight wrap it up lesgo." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -> `OptSel != 5 && (repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y')`. `&&` has higher precedence than `||`.

Comment: changing that does not affect the code at all, the problem mainly comes from the void Repeatcheck function

Comment: `void Repeatcheck(char repeat){` you passed `repeat` by value so if it gets into the while() and changes the value of `repeat` the code that calls Repeatcheck() will not see that change to `repeat` because it's a copy.